# Does a Liapunov function h to have all the variables explicitly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have for example, a system like this
$$\begin{matrix}
\dot{x}=f(x,y)  & \\ 
\dot{y}=g(x,y) & 
\end{matrix}$$
in which i have to prove stability using a Lyapunov function. Now, if i have function like $V(x,y)=x^2$ supposedly fulfilling all the requirements in the theorem, is this possible?.

Does a Liapunov function needs to have all the variables explicitly? that is, something like  $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2 $.
I feel like I am missing some property in the theorem.

Comment: Lyapunov function (in a strict sense) must satisfy $L>0$ for all $(x,y)\neq (\hat x,\hat y)$, where $(\hat x,\hat y)$ is the equilibrium. In your case, if you assume that $(0,0)$ is your equilibrium, $x^2$ is also zero along the $y$-axis

Comment: You're right, thank you.